# Android Studio Toolbar doesn't show several features (like constraints)

Tags: android-studio

I am new to AS and following this guide: [Android Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html)
where it says
"Make sure Show Constraints is on. The tooltip in the toolbar should read Hide Constraints  (because they're now showing).
Make sure Autoconnect is off. The tooltip in the toolbar should read Turn On Autoconnect  (because it's now off)."
I can't find neither of those in the toolbar, see Screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot toolbar]

Even though I have the dependecy in gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

First dependecies is from the overall Project to show you the current version, second dependencies is the build.gradle in the app folder
So yeah, what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it: I had to convert into Constraint Layout first, right click on the Blueprint to find that option

Comment: love you for that, been struggling with that for over an hour.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to read and follow the directions closely. For the "Open the Layout Editor" in the [Android Studios guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui#open), the workplace setup needs to be in design mode with the activity_main.xml open. For step #4 to #7 (design/blueprint, constraints, autoconnect, margins), the referenced toolbars are **directly above the app layout/blueprint**. The  guide is **not** referring to the side panels or standard toolbars at the top of the application.

Since the guide may change, I am specifically referring to the steps: #4 switching to blueprint, #5 show all constraints, #6 disable Autoconnect, and #7 adjust default margins.

See the link [toolbar screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJd91.png) for a visualization of Android Studio and the corresponding step.